# @Future method is not getting called. No logs, no exception no errors. When records are inserted through REST API call from an external system

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, future

Orders custom object have a lookup on Contact. Each Order will have a corresponding contact. A contact can have multiple orders.

When an order's is inserted through Salesforce or any tools for inserting, the order/orders are insert and the contact Trigger is triggered successfully. The Method to send data to SQL database is through a Future method which calls an API.

When we insert orders from SQL database through a job the contact trigger is triggered, the control goes till the future method and exits the future method without calling the API. No future method is being called at all. The control skips the future method. Since future method is not being called, we do not get any logs. we are not getting any exceptions or errors regarding this. With the debug logs I'm able to tell how far the execution is happening. Obviously since the future is not called, we do not get logs for future parts.

Here is part of the code that which has the future method.

```
public with sharing class Direct_SendContactsToDB {
    public Direct_SendContactsToDB() {

    }
    public void sendContactToDB(List<SendContactsToDBParams> pramList){
        try {
            system.debug('@@@ before the method');
            system.debug('@@@ before the method--->'+pramList);
            sendContactToDBFuture(JSON.serialize(pramList));
            system.debug('@@@ after the method');
        }Catch(Exception ex){
            new LogException().log(ex);
            System.debug(' Exception here : '+ex.getLineNumber()+'-'+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @future(Callout = true)
    public static void sendContactToDBFuture(String reqPrams){
        try{
            system.debug('@@@ inside future');
            system.debug('@@@ inside future reqPrams--->'+reqPrams);
            String baseEndPointUrl = 'callout:Direct_APIServiceWrapper/';
            String endPoint;
            String  accessToken = Direct_Utility.getIdaasToken('StoreIdaasAccessToken','Idaas');
            Map<String, String> headerMap = new Map<String, String>();
            headerMap.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headerMap.put('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            endPoint = baseEndPointUrl +'sendcontactstoDB';
            try{
                HTTPResponse response = Direct_Utility.makeCallOut(headerMap,reqPrams,endPoint,'POST');
                System.debug('@@@ reposne : '+response.getStatusCode()+' :: '+response.getbody());
            }Catch(Exception e){
                System.debug(' Exception here : '+e.getLineNumber()+'-'+e.getMessage());
            }
                    
        }Catch(Exception ex){
            new LogException().log(ex);
            System.debug(' Exception here : '+ex.getLineNumber()+'-'+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "SQL Job". Are you talking about a Salesforce Apex job or some REST API call from an external system onto Salesforce? Also, what is the context of execution for Direct_SendContactsToDB? Is this being called from a trigger? If so, please read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) about why this is a broken pattern, and to discover an alternative approach.

Comment: Worth also seeing [this second example](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) of how to manage callouts from data updates.

Comment: Thanks Phil, worked with Queueable.

Comment: If using queuable directly from a trigger, be aware this will also fail if you have multiple DML or bulk (> 200 record) DML in an already asynchronous context.